# Multiple plots on same graph using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I would like to plot x^c for different values of c on the same graph using just for loop and matplotlib library, with different colors for each function . When I try using for loop, the output just shows one graph.

****CODE****

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
for i in range(-10,10,21):
    if i<0:
        plt.plot(x,x**(abs(1/i)))
    elif i>0:
        plt.plot(x,x**i)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `range()` function right now produces only a single value of -10. May be you need

```
for i in range(-10,10,1):
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: But what if i want continuous rainbow colors from the first function to the last

Comment: @AthulDev : That would be a different question.